# Search and account for variable row location of desired text

Tags: excel, vba, csv, variables

The Macro I currently have utilises text-based data pulled to a CSV format file, with most text dumped row by row into column `A`. Some data is in Column `B`.
The report pulled from the system to a CSV file is generally formatted into 5 rows of data per account.

However, for some accounts, there are 1-4 junk rows of data between the first 5 (`data_1`, `data_2`, `data_3`, `data_4`, `data_5`) pieces of required data and the last two, i.e `data_6` and `data_7`

My current search method is to use column and search range

```
sh.Range("A" & i)
```

then for each subsequent row

```
sh.Range("A" & i + 1)
```

However, this doesn't work for `data_6` and `data_7` in all instances as the CSV file report output is not standardised across all accounts.

Please can somebody advise of a way to account for the variable location in rows to search for the relevant/required

```
Option Explicit: Option Compare Text: Const START_ROW = 2: Dim wb As Workbook: Dim sh As Worksheet: Dim wbOut As Workbook: Dim shOut As Worksheet: Dim max As Long: Dim index As Long
Sub processNow()
Dim i, count As Long: Dim file As Variant: Dim data_1, data_2, data_3, data_4, data_5, data_6, data_7 As String: On Error GoTo errHandler: file = Application.GetOpenFilename()
If file = False Then
Exit Sub
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Application.EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler: Set wb = Workbooks.Open(file): Set sh = wb.Sheets(1): Set wbOut = Workbooks.Add: Set shOut = wbOut.Sheets(1): max = LastRow(sh): index = 2: Call addHeaders: frmProgress.Show vbModeless: For i = START_ROW To max: frmProgress.setMessagePercent "Processing row " & i & " of " & max, i * 100 / max
If Mid(sh.Range("A" & i), 7, 1) = "/" Then
count = count + 1
If count > 1 Then
data_1 = sh.Range("A" & i): data_2 = sh.Range("B" & i): data_3 = sh.Range("A" & i + 1): data_4 = sh.Range("A" & i + 2): data_5 = sh.Range("A" & i + 3): data_6 = sh.Range("A" & i + 4): data_7 = sh.Range("A" & i + 5): processData data_1, data_2, data_3, data_4, data_5, data_6, data_7
End If
End If
Next i: shOut.UsedRange.AutoFilter: shOut.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit: shOut.Activate: wb.Close False: Application.ScreenUpdating = True: MsgBox "VALIDATION AUDIT COMPLETE", vbInformation
cleanStep:
On Error Resume Next: Unload frmProgress: Application.ScreenUpdating = True: Application.EnableCancelKey = xlInterrupt: Exit Sub
errHandler:
MsgBox "Sorry got error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical: GoTo cleanStep: End Sub
```

Comment: You might write each line of code in a separate line and remove the `:` in order to make the code easier to read.

Comment: Those colons make your code unreadable (or at least not without some extra effort)

Answer (score 0):

If I've interpreted your criteria correctly then:

Below is a potential way to modify the code to read the first 5 data elements and then retrieve the last two elements of the data set (assumes there can be 0 to n lines of (junk) data preceding the last two items.

I've commented out the replaced lines rather than deleting so you can easily see what was changed.  Also, some of the `Declaration` lists are probably creating Types that you did not intend - comments made there as well.

```
Option Explicit: Option Compare Text: Const START_ROW = 2: Dim wb As Workbook: Dim sh As Worksheet: Dim wbOut As Workbook: Dim shOut As Worksheet: Dim max As Long: Dim index As Long

'Recommend more meaningful names than data_1, etc...but retained the names for now
'Declaring a UserDefinedType to make it easier to pass all the data elements between procedures
Private Type DataElementSet
    data_1 As String
    data_2 As String
    data_3 As String
    data_4 As String
    data_5 As String
    data_6 As String
    data_7 As String
End Type

Sub processNow()
'Note: As declared below, i is a Variant
Dim i, itemCount As Long: Dim file As Variant

'Note: As declared below, data_7 is a String, data_1 thru data_6 are Variants
'Dim data_1, data_2, data_3, data_4, data_5, data_6, data_7 As String
On Error GoTo errHandler: file = Application.GetOpenFilename()
If file = False Then
Exit Sub
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Application.EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler: Set wb = Workbooks.Open(file): Set sh = wb.Sheets(1): Set wbOut = Workbooks.Add: Set shOut = wbOut.Sheets(1): max = LastRow(sh): index = 2: Call addHeaders: frmProgress.Show vbModeless

': For i = START_ROW To max: frmProgress.setMessagePercent "Processing row " & i & " of " & max, i * 100 / max
'If Mid(sh.Range("A" & i), 7, 1) = "/" Then
'Count = Count + 1
'If Count > 1 Then
'data_1 = sh.Range("A" & i): data_2 = sh.Range("B" & i): data_3 = sh.Range("A" & i + 1): data_4 = sh.Range("A" & i + 2): data_5 = sh.Range("A" & i + 3): data_6 = sh.Range("A" & i + 4): data_7 = sh.Range("A" & i + 5)
'
'
'processData data_1, data_2, data_3, data_4, data_5, data_6, data_7
'End If
'End If
'Next i

ParseAndProcessData sh, START_ROW, max, itemCount

shOut.UsedRange.AutoFilter: shOut.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit: shOut.Activate: wb.Close False: Application.ScreenUpdating = True: MsgBox "VALIDATION AUDIT COMPLETE", vbInformation
cleanStep:
On Error Resume Next: Unload frmProgress: Application.ScreenUpdating = True: Application.EnableCancelKey = xlInterrupt: Exit Sub
errHandler:
MsgBox "Sorry got error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical: GoTo cleanStep: End Sub


Private Sub ParseAndProcessData(sh As Worksheet, ByVal startRow As Long, ByVal max As Long, ByRef itemCount As Long)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim data As DataElementSet

    For i = startRow To max
        frmProgress.setMessagePercent "Processing row " & i & " of " & max, i * 100 / max
        If IsStartOfNewDataElementSet(sh, i) Then
            itemCount = itemCount + 1
            If itemCount > 1 Then
                data.data_1 = sh.Range("A" & i)
                data.data_2 = sh.Range("B" & i)
                data.data_3 = sh.Range("A" & i + 1)
                data.data_4 = sh.Range("A" & i + 2)
                data.data_5 = sh.Range("A" & i + 3)
                i = LoadLastTwoDataElements(sh, i + 4, data)

                processData data.data_1, data.data_2, data.data_3, data.data_4, data.data_5, data.data_6, data.data_7
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Private Function LoadLastTwoDataElements(sh As Worksheet, index As Long, ByRef data As DataElementSet) As Long
    Dim beyond5 As Collection
    Set beyond5 = New Collection
    Dim indexOfLastElements As Long
    For indexOfLastElements = index To index + 10   ' could be less but must be at least 6
        If IsStartOfNewDataElementSet(sh, indexOfLastElements) Then
            data.data_6 = beyond5.Item(beyond5.Count - 1)
            data.data_7 = beyond5.Item(beyond5.Count)
            LoadLastTwoDataElements = indexOfLastElements - 1
            Exit Function
        End If
        beyond5.Add sh.Range("A" & indexOfLastElements)
    Next indexOfLastElements
    LoadLastTwoDataElements = indexOfLastElements - 1
End Function

Private Function IsStartOfNewDataElementSet(sh As Worksheet, index As Long) As Boolean
    IsStartOfNewDataElementSet = Mid(sh.Range("A" & index), 7, 1) = "/"
End Function

'Stubs to allow code to compile...added frmProgress.setMessagePercent locally
Private Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet) As Long

End Function

Private Sub addHeaders()
End Sub

Private Sub processData(data_1 As String, data_2 As String, data_3 As String, data_4 As String, data_5 As String, data_6 As String, data_7 As String)

End Sub
```